# Back button in jQuery Mobile fires twice

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap to develop a small Android app.

I get the following problem:

I have a page A, which includes a Google map and a link in an `infowindow`.

When I click the link, the app will switch to the page B, and when I click the back button on the page B, the page will unexpectedly go back to page B and not to page A.

During the back-page transition, the page blinks. It seems like the page change event fires twice.

Comment: Does page A link directly to page B, or does it go through some middleman page that redirects to page B? That is the most common case when I see this problem on sites out there. You click on a link, it goes to a page that redirects to the actual page (call it page B), and when you click the back button once, you are going back to the page that just redirects you back to page B.

Comment: $.mobile.changePage($("#outagedetailPage"));

Comment: it goes to page outagedetailpage directly but when it back to page a page a will call a $('#Page').live('pageshow', function(event){}); will it cause the problem?

Comment: I don't know. Try commenting out that event handler and see if it starts working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the Phonegap to 2.1.0

they have fixed some of the issues with back and menu buttons